# QueryDSL CaseBuilder does not work with java.util.Date

Tags: hibernate, querydsl

When I do this, I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported constant Mon Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2021`

```
DateTimeExpression<Date> startOfMonth = new CaseBuilder()
            .when(order.dueDate.lt(day))
            .then(new Date())
            .otherwise(new Date());
```

Seems like such a simple query. I don't understand what's going wrong.

I'm using QueryDSL 3.6, Hibernate 5.1, and Postgres 10.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JPQL/HQL doesn't allow for parameters in a `CASE WHEN` expression. You have to replace the constant with a literal. Something like the following:

```java
.when(order.dueDate.lt(Expressions.templateExpression(Date.class, "'2021-01-01 00:00:00'"))
```

The constants in the "THEN" and "ELSE" expressions should be fine.

Comment: If I do this I get the error "ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= text".

If I add a  type cast, I get the error "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 6"

Comment: You need to use a JPQL cast instead of a SQL cast. Perhaps `Expressions.dateOperation(Date.class, JPQLOps.CAST, Expressions.stringTemplate("'2020-01-01'"), Expressions.constant(Date.class))`?

Comment: If I do this I get the error `HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class:`